# @Autowired is Null in Spring Boot but same is accessible through Application Context

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, autowired

Through @Autowired i am not able to access the @Component/@Service/@Respository/@Controller class objects in other java files which has **@Component** annotation (Step 1: Approach) with the Step 1 approach getting **Null pointer Exception**, but same i could achieve using (Step 2: Approach).

Can anyone please tell me why i am not able to achieve using Step 1 approach:

### FYI- I've searched in my entire project i have not used/called/initialized the @Component classes using `new` method for the autowired class still i getting the issue as "Null Pointer Exception"

**Step 1: Using @Autowired Annotation**

```
@Component
public class Processor {

        @Autowired
        PropertyConfigurator propconfigrator; --> Getting here as null pointer Exception

public void getDetails(){

System.out.println ("Application URL +propconfigrator.getProperties().getProperty("appURL"));

}
}
```

**Step 2: Using ApplicationContext Interface with/without @AutoWired annotation** . I am able to get the property value from PropertyConfigurator java file

```
@Component
public class Processor {

        @Autowired
        PropertyConfigurator propconfigrator = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(PropertyConfigurator.class);

public void getDetails(){

System.out.println ("Application URL +propconfigrator.getProperties().getProperty("appURL"));

}
}
```

**ApplicationContextHolder.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;   
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

**PropertyConfigurator.java file**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Service
@Configurable
public class PropertyConfigurator {

    private final Properties properties;

    public Properties getProperties () {
        return properties;
    }

    public  PropertyConfigurator(){
            properties = new Properties();
            try {
  properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dbconfig.properties"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use @Configurable annotation? In the code you postet, it doesn't make sense. @Configurable is only needed in cases when instances of this class are not createt by spring.

Comment: Thanks!!. I removed but still facing the same issue as "Null Pointer Exception".

Answer (score 0):

I have changed into Constructor Injection Autowiring as below with the step 1 approach of above (Not using Step 2. It resolved my issue finally.

Not sure why Spring is not able to inject the bean without using the Constructor Autowiring.

**Step 1: Using @Autowired Annotation with Constructor**

```
@Component
public class Processor {

@Autowired
    public Processor (PropertyConfigurator propconfigrator) {
        this.propconfigrator = propconfigrator;
}
public void getDetails(){

System.out.println ("Application URL +propconfigrator.getProperties().getProperty("appURL"));

}
}
```